# Test Data Preparation for Mockito Test

Tags: junit, mockito

Normally, sometime we need to test some business methods which needs return lots of data from DAO layer, and used Mockito mocks the DAO layer. So we need to prepare the return data from DAO methods. And normally it needs build tons of beans.
Is there any good way to build the data easily without DB(even in memory)?
Example:

```
when(personDAO.findAll()).then(new Answer<List<Person>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Person> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return JSONUtil.parse(file, Person.class);

            // ... or ...
            Person person1 = new Person(1, "troy");
            Person person2 = new Person(2, "linda");
            // ... more than 3 person
            return Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person....);
        }

});
```

PS: as I can think a way to build a JSON file, serialise the list of beans into file, and before we mock the methods return we deserialise into list of beans.

Comment: What kind of test you are trying to do?  For unit tests, you should rarely need to do what you mentioned.  Just return a mock `Person` object or a simple `Person` object (with some test-relevant data set) should normally be done.  If it is an integration test, I doubt if Mockito is suitable in this case.  You may want to actually connect to DB and prepare data in it

Comment: but sometime you know we have a method which will group person by department, and also will aggregate something, so that unit needs enough data for testing, that's the purpose.

Comment: In case of unit tests, I don't see difficulties to manually construct such data by code, with aid of some util methods.  imho, when you are writing unit tests, you should make sure for each test case, the pre-requisite conditions are clear.  By constructing data from some other file etc is going to go against it

Comment: Absolutely, if the test case is simple enough. But I don't want to build these more than 3 instance by code, and the 3 variable name maybe are `person1`, `person2` and `person3`, which are meaningless. Even if the person contains multiple attributes, such as department, and under department, it has some object attribute. So if we build these test data in code, it's really hard to read it and managable.

Comment: I don't see how using a separate file, written in JSON or anything else, would make it clearer than just using Java code. If you want ot test a method that groups elements by departments, you just really need three or 4 persons that are in two different departments: `personWithDepartment("a"), personWithDepartment("b"), personWithDepartment("a"), personWithDepartment("b")`. How is that a problem?

Comment: 2 things I want to improve: 1. name convention, 2. if the department has some object in it, you still need to build the object attribute, which means you need to write tons of java code to build the test data, which is not readable.

Comment: 1. You should build the object just enough for your testing.  2. You don't need the code to build the object to be super readable, you need your invocation to it to be readable (which is what really matters with your test case).  3. If you can write the object content in JSON, I can almost guarantee you can write equally readable object creation code in Java.  The latter is better because you are clear on what is the content by simply looking at your test, without need to read another separate JSON file.

Comment: 4. for the department example, you should hide the object attribute setup in the helper function, so in your test case, you just need to know: ok, this is a person in department A.   To be honest, I have go through similar approach you wanna use.  I was in a case with even higher need than you, that I was setting up DB records for testing DAO/Repository, for which I used CSV + DB Unit as helper.  However, it turned out that although the test seems easier to write, it is actually harder to understand, so for all later test I setup in my test itself, and find way to make it readable instead

Comment: @sgyyz Even if it's test code, you can still produce all of the well-factored helpers you might need. Yes, there's Java code to be written, but like every other piece of Java code you can just write it once and call it easily from there on out. Write yourself a TestDataBuilder (or similar) and you'll find it pretty easy to work from there.